# DoCapture in vb.net with wsdl

Tags: vb.net, paypal, vb.net-2010, paypal-sandbox

i need to develop a method to implement the doCapture method in paypal.

I use vb.net in Visual Studio 2010.
i created a testing winform project add a service reference with the url= "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl"

then i had 2 problem:

1.Error 3   'y' is already declared in this enum.
so i remove on of the "y" in the Reference file .

2.needed to delete the extra () from Reference file ,like in  `Private merchantDataField()() As TupleType`

then i added this code `

```
    Dim i As ws.PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient = New ws.PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient()

    Dim _DoCaptureReq As ws.DoCaptureReq = New ws.DoCaptureReq


    Dim _DoCaptureResponseType As ws.DoCaptureResponseType = New ws.DoCaptureResponseType
    Dim _CustomSecurityHeaderType As ws.CustomSecurityHeaderType = New ws.CustomSecurityHeaderType
    _DoCaptureReq.DoCaptureRequest = New DoCaptureRequestType()
    _DoCaptureReq.DoCaptureRequest.Amount = New BasicAmountType()
    _DoCaptureReq.DoCaptureRequest.Amount.Value = "10"
    _DoCaptureReq.DoCaptureRequest.Amount.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.ILS
    _DoCaptureReq.DoCaptureRequest.AuthorizationID = 122334



    Dim APIAccountName As String = "aa"
    Dim APIAccountPassword As String = "bb"
    Dim Signature As String = "cc"

    _CustomSecurityHeaderType.Credentials = New UserIdPasswordType()
    _CustomSecurityHeaderType.Credentials.Username = APIAccountName
    _CustomSecurityHeaderType.Credentials.Password = APIAccountPassword
    _CustomSecurityHeaderType.Credentials.Signature = Signature
    _CustomSecurityHeaderType.Credentials.Subject = ""



    _DoCaptureResponseType = i.DoCapture(_CustomSecurityHeaderType, _DoCaptureReq)`
```

I get an error when i call i.DoCapture (last line)

> "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority
>   'api-aa.sandbox.paypal.com'."

here is the config with the url i use:

```
<client>
            <endpoint address="https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="PayPalAPISoapBinding" contract="ws.PayPalAPIInterface"
                name="PayPalAPI" />
            <endpoint address="https://api-aa.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="PayPalAPIAASoapBinding" contract="ws.PayPalAPIAAInterface"
                name="PayPalAPIAA" />
        </client>
```

How can i fix this problem?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you're using signatures, set the endpoint address to https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/.